# Error SSL on XAMPP 7.0.23: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

Tags: php, ssl, https, xampp, wamp

I am trying to run a Site WEB on "Private Network" or by "Public Network via HTTPS (SSL) on XAMPP. I flow this etaps:

1- "C:\xampp\apache\makecert.bat" to make the Certificate.

2- httpd.conf Remove (#) form LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

3- php.ini Remove (;) from extension=php_openssl.dll

Restart apache and chrome!

localhost uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

https://192.168.1.100 Peer’s Certificate issuer is not recognized. 
HTTP Strict Transport Security: false 
HTTP Public Key Pinning: false

Comment: You're using a self-signed certificate, what did you expect? Just add an exception in your browser and carry on.

Comment: can i use SSL without add an exception in my browser, as google ...etc

Comment: On `localhost`? Not really - you'll either need to add an exception in the browser or trust the certificate at the OS level. More information at: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Comment: i use xxx.ddns.net to access this web, can i use SSL without add en exception in my browser ???

Comment: Nope: https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/can-you-add-an-ssl-to-a-hostname-attached-to-no-ips-domain/

Comment: thank you for your help, can i use public ip Adresse ?

Comment: SSL (technically TLS now) is tied to a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) such as *www.yourdomain.ext* and, to avoid the `SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER` error the certificate must be signed by a recognised Certificate Authority (CA) - they validate that the domain belongs to *you* (differing levels of validation are required depending on the certificate type)... the whole thing is *entirely* about trust, there's no actual difference in encryption between a self-signed certificate and one from a CA - it's not the IP address that's the issue as such.

Comment: hi thank you for your responce, i dont have domanename but i have fixed public Ip Adresse, how can i avoid the SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER error of the Certificate ???, I am a beginner in this domain, can you help me please

Comment: Without a domain name you *can't* - it's the domain name that's verified with the CA; all you can do is use a self-signed cert, as you are doing, and add an exception in the browser. I suspect your *best* bet would be to talk to noip (as you're already using their free service) about their *Plus Managed DNS* service with the *SSL Upgrade*

Answer (score -1):

Open your "apache/conf/httpd.conf" file and add the following lines (right after closing `</Directory>` tag):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost:443
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

then restart your "Apache" and check back again "https://localhost".

Comment: What part of this answer is addressing the issue that self-signed certificates trigger a self-signed certificate error?